# Changing Kernel version from 4.10 to 4.4

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, kernel, dpkg, cuda

I am installing CUDA Toolkit on Ubuntu 16.04, in the supported distribution table it's written that the Kernel must be "4.4". When I run:

```
uname -r
```

I get "4.10.0-42-generic". I tried to install it but it failed with the following message:

```
It is likely that 4.10.0-42-generic belongs to a chroot's host
Building initial module for 4.10.0-42-generic
Done.
bbswitch:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
Setting up vdpau-driver-all:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.32~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-21-lowlatency
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, how can I move back to that version of Kernel?

Note: "I have a specific directory "/boot" for booting files which is 250 MB sized and now it's "%80 full".

Comment: There should more informative messages above the `E: Sub-process ...` line. Can you please edit into your post? Also, are you sure the CUDA Toolkit doesn't work at 4.10? I think the requirement is likely to be *minimum requirement*, and since your version is newer, it might be fine.

Comment: Try to do `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-21-lowlatency` ?

Comment: @dobey: Do you mind posting that as an answer please?